# Azure DevOps Pull-Request: Additional commits in a existing Pull-Request trigger rebuilds, ignoring the Path filter in the Build Policy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-repos

I've created a build policy to run a CI pipeline if a part of the codebase has been changed.
I want to excluded files from retriggering a build.

[image: The path filter includes everything, but excludes the README.md file]

When creating a pull-request with changes in the README.md file, the build is not triggered (as expected).

When creating a pull-request with changes in other files, the build triggered (as expected)

When creating a pull-request with a change in another file, the build is triggered, but when I commit a change to the README.md file, it fails the current build and starts a new build. (not expected, I expect the path filter to prevent a rebuild because the file should be ignored for this build)

It seems the build policy path filter only works when creating the pull request.

Is there a way to commit files to an existing pull-request without triggering a rebuild?

Comment: Trying to understand: are you pushing a commit to a file in this ignore path in the source branch, and the build triggers again ?

Comment: @jmuz3 Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I could reproduce this situation.

Here is a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/668860/build-validation-pipeline-gets-cancelled-when-pipe.html) about the explanation about this situation.

> Is there a way to commit files to an existing pull-request without
>   triggering a rebuild?

You could refer to the workaround in the ticket above.

For another workaround: you could try to set the **“Trigger”**   as **‘Manual’** in **"Build validation"**.

In this case, you can manually queue build in Pull Request.

When a new commit is submitted to the source branch, the current build can continue to run without directly failing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation why this is not supported in the ticket is helpful and this is an edge-case which they don't want to support. 

Setting the "Trigger" to "Manual" will solve this problem, but I prefer to keep the trigger set to Automatic because its great for 95% of our pull requests without this problem

Comment: This comment from the ticket is also helpful: "I was able to work around it by using a CI build, actually. Now the PR builds don't create the commit; after the PR is completed, the CI build creates the commit and an auto-complete PR into the branch. Thanks again for taking time to reply."

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve the problem with rebuilding on a new commit.

However, I could solve our particular problem. There's a step in our pipeline which generates files and commits them, which trigger the rebuild. I've added a step which checks if the files are already added and skips committing a generated again.

To check if the file already exists in the pull request, I use the following command:

`git diff origin/master -- {filename} --exit-code --shortstat`